# Items showing duplicated in List View, SQlite adds "true"?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio, android-sqlite

So I' currently making my way through syncing a SQLite Database to Firebase Database.

Got to a point wher I don't really understand whats happening in my code :P

Data is successfully added to SQLite and since I logged this whole process, I know it is only added once, also I set the Text to UNIQUE
When I want to display it in a ListView, 
it displays every entry duplicated, like this:

[ListView Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45jdd.jpg)

So in my Log, it says "adding true to array" when "true" should be a specific name like Drawing and Painting, but displays Drawing and Painting anyway. Confusing! 
I even tried to handle this with exceptions that prevent the ArrayList from duplicate entrys...

Any Help is highly appreciated! :)

```
selectedName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

    // get data and append to a list

    Cursor data = databaseHelper.getFirstSubData(selectedName);

//----------------Snipped of DatabseHelper--------------//

    public Cursor getFirstSubData(String mainCat){
    // SELECT SubCats FROM first_sub_table WHERE 'mainCat' = main cat
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query1 = "SELECT " + FIRST_SUB_COL3 +  " FROM " + COURSES_FIRST_SUB_TABLE
            + " WHERE " + FIRST_SUB_COL2 + " = '" + mainCat + "'";

    Log.d(TAG, "SELECT " + FIRST_SUB_COL3 +  " FROM " + COURSES_FIRST_SUB_TABLE
            + " WHERE " + FIRST_SUB_COL2 + " = '" + mainCat + "'");

    Cursor data = database.rawQuery(query1, null);
    return data;
}
// ---------------------End of snippet------------------//
    ArrayList<String> sublistData = new ArrayList<>();

    Log.d(TAG, "Cursor is on Position: " + data.getPosition());

    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside the while loop");
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor is on Position: " + data.getPosition());
        // get the value from the database in column 0 then add it to the array list
        sublistData.add(data.getString(0));
        Log.d(TAG, "ADDING " + sublistData.add(data.getString(0)) + " to ARRAY");
    }

        String size = Integer.toString(sublistData.size());
        Log.d(TAG, "SIZE OF ARRAY IN SUB CAT IS " + size);

        final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sublistData);
        lvSubItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Try removing `sublistData.add(data.getString(0))` from the `Log.d...` line, as this will add a 2nd  and thus duplicate element as opposed to getting the value of the 1st element.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for helping out!...Thats what happens if you copy&paste things and work for 12 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the following lines of code:-

```
        sublistData.add(data.getString(0));
        Log.d(TAG, "ADDING " + sublistData.add(data.getString(0)) + " to ARRAY");
```

The first line adds an element with the data and is correct. However, the second line by repeating the first line adds a 2nd element to the array with the same value. So for each iteration of the loop 2 entries are added.

The fix is to not repeat using `sublistData.add(data.getString(0))`. You should probably use `Log.d(TAG, "ADDING " + data.getString(0) + " to ARRAY");` for the second line.